# How to remove the bottom border of the selected tab in chrome using css

Tags: css, google-chrome

[image: This image is regarding the tabs which i see on google chrome which needs to be fixed. like, the selected tab should not have the bottom line][image]

In internet explorer we get a strraight line.in chrome we get distorted lines and rest of all the browsers have the desired case.which is shown by first image. Kindly tell some code to achieve this as i need it very badly. here is the code:

```
ul#tabs li a { 
    color: #a09b95;
    padding: 6px 15px 7px 15px;
    padding: 6px 15px 5px 15px\9;           /* IE-only fix */
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c9c3ba;
    border-right: 1px solid #c9c3ba;
/*  background-color: #ffffff; */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#f3efeb)); /* Saf4+, Chrome */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f3efeb); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+, iOS 5+ */
    background:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f3efeb); /* FF3.6+ */
    background:     -ms-linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #F3EFEB); /* IE 8 */
    background:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f3efeb); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background:         linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #f3efeb); /* IE9+ */
    -pie-background:    linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #F3EFEB); /* IE 6-7 via CSS3Pie */
    behavior: url("http://ocw5.mit.edu/styles/pie/PIE.php");
}   


ul#tabs li a.selected {
    color: #b30838;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    background-color: #fff;
    background: none;
    -pie-background: none;
    behavior: url("http://ocw5.mit.edu/styles/pie/PIE.php");
}


/* Chrome/Safari-only CHP tab border fix */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {

    ul#tabs {
        margin: 19px 0 -1px 0;
        outline: 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Code please? We are not mind / code readers!

Comment: Post your code in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and be more specific what is your actual problem.

Comment: Hi @Benjamin Nice to meet you here! :P

Comment: which one is the correct?

Comment: @punithasubramaniv Should be the left one!

Comment: @punithasubramaniv we couldn't trigger it yet the author must be more specific

Comment: The OP should have a `margin-bottom: -1px` for the `<ul>` if he has one! Agree?

Comment: we want the code to know which tag we can apply the css. Anyway It will do like ul{ border-bottom:1px solid #fff; } somthing like this

Comment: the left one is the desired scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
ul#tabs li {margin-bottom: -1px;}
```

Comment: where should i add this. i tried it in (ul#tabs li a:) section my code given above....but didnt work.

Comment: @Ranjan Try `position: relative; bottom: -1px;`

Comment: Just add it in the end.